409 Conflict with Hostgator
I am getting a 409 Conflict error after uploading files to Hostgator server.  They initially said it was an issue with the nameserver, but that has since been resolved.  Now they are saying that it's an issue with my code.  I am trying to narrow down the possibilities, but I am getting frustrated.
I built this site using Docker.  Here is the Dockerfile:
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

Now I did notice that Hostgator is using PHP 8.3.6.  If that is the problem, you can stop right here and let me know. I am leaning towards it not being the problem.
I'm using jQuery to grab the form data and sending to the PHP script like this:
$.post("process/contact.php", { cobj: cobj }, function(data) {
  if (data == "success") {
    toastr.success("good");
  } else {
    toastr.error("fail");
  }
});

The contact.php looks like this:
<?php
use phpmailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require_once '../phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require_once '../phpmailer/SMTP.php';
require_once '../phpmailer/Exception.php';

if(isset($_POST['cobj'])) {
  $value = $_POST['cobj'];
  
  $fullname = $value['fullname'];
  $email = strtoupper($value['email']);
  $phonenumber = $value['phonenumber'];
  $message = $value['message'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;      
  $mail->isSMTP();                                        
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';                             
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                                            
  $mail->Port = 587; 
  $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxx', 'Mailer');
  $mail->addAddress('yyyyyyyyyyy', 'Receiver');      
  $mail->addReplyTo('xxxxxxxxxxx', 'No Reply'); 

  $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
       'verify_peer' => false,
       'verify_peer_name' => false,
       'allow_self_signed' => true
      )
    );  
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    
    $mail->Subject = 'Message';
    $mail->Body    = '<h3>You received a message.</h3>
                        <p>From: '.$fullname.'</p>
                        <p>Email: '.$email.'</p>
                        <p>Phone: '.$phonenumber.'</p>
                        <p>Message: '.$message.'</p>
                        <p>Sent on: '.$date.'</p>
                        <p>Please follow up.</p>';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Error';
    } else {
        echo 'Success';
    }        
}
?>

I probably didn't need to include all the code from contact.php but I did just in case.
I had commented everything out of the contact.php and was still getting the 409 conflict error.
It appears the PHP mailer version I'm using is 5.  Not sure if that could be the problem.
Regardless, everything is working locally.  How can I solve it on the live site?

Not sure who downvoted but your code does not actually have any part that would return a 409 return status. I think the problem may be configuration outside your code. Not sure where though, could be in your containers or in hostgator

@apokryfos - thank you for that information.  I didn't think there was anything wrong with my code, but wanted to be sure.  I got off the phone with Hostgator about an hour ago, and they said it's something to do with the fact that I was still using Yahoo's smtp host.  I created an email account through Hostgator and updated my code to read as such.  They said it may take a few hours to update on their side.  We'll see...

I spoke with Hostgator multiple times.  First they said it was a problem with the nameserver.  When they made that adjustment, it still didn't work.
Then they said it was a problem with the email account.  When we made the adjustments, I still was getting the same error.
Finally, after escalating the call, it turns out it was a "whitelisting" issue.  Apparently, the form needed to be whitelisted.  I am not sure why, but if you come across the same 409 conflict error, mention "whitelisting the form", and hopefully that will solve the problem.
